# How can I make a variable in custom directives which can be access in controller file or in any other javascript file of the same app?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to declare a variable in custom directives which can be access any where in same app.

My requirement is to declare a variable in custom directive and whose value will be access any where by me.

> I want to declare variable in below directive

```
.directive('ngListSelect', ['$filter',
    function($filter) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          selectedListItems: "=selectedList",
          availableListItems: "=availableList",
          key: "@key",
          buttonStyle: "@buttonStyle",
          panelStyle: "@panelStyle",
          height: "@height",
          width: "@width",
          availableLabel: "@availableLabel",
          selectedLabel: "@selectedLabel"
        },
        templateUrl: 'ngListSelect.html',
        compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
          return {
            pre: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
              scope.availableText = angular.isUndefined(scope.availableLabel) ? 'Available' : scope.availableLabel;
              scope.selectedText = angular.isUndefined(scope.selectedLabel) ? 'Selected' : scope.selectedLabel;
              scope.height = angular.isUndefined(scope.height) ? '144px' : scope.height;
              scope.width = angular.isUndefined(scope.width) ? '640px' : scope.width;
              scope.buttonStyle = angular.isUndefined(scope.buttonStyle) ? 'alpha' : scope.buttonStyle;
              scope.buttonClass = getColor(scope.buttonStyle, 'button');
              scope.panelStyle = angular.isUndefined(scope.panelStyle) ? 'alpha' : scope.panelStyle;
              scope.panelClass = getColor(scope.panelStyle, 'panel');
              scope.leftMouseSelectedItems = [];
              scope.rightMouseSelectedItems = [];
              scope.dropdownStyle = {
                height: scope.height
              };
              scope.containerStyle = {
                width: scope.width
              };
              scope.ascendingOrderFlag = true;
              scope.topLetter = 'A';
              scope.bottomLetter = 'Z';
              scope.letterStyle = {
                mainContainer:{"width":"10px","line-height":"9px"},
                letter:{"font-size":"10px","float":"left","font-weight":"600","font-family":"sans-serif"},
                letterCrimson:{"font-size":"10px","float":"left","font-weight":"600","font-family":"sans-serif", "color":"crimson"},
                letterDarkblue:{"font-size":"10px","float":"left","font-weight":"600","font-family":"sans-serif", "color":"darkblue"}, 
                arrow:{"font-size":"25px"}
              }; 

              if (scope.availableListItems[0] instanceof Object) {
                scope.leftSelectNgOption = "item as item." + scope.key + " for item in availableListItems | orderBy:'" + scope.key + "'";
                scope.rightSelectNgOption = "item as item." + scope.key + " for item  in selectedListItems";
                scope.availableListItems = getUnique(scope.availableListItems, scope.key);
              } 
              else {
                scope.leftSelectNgOption = "item as item for item in availableListItems | orderBy:'toString()'";
                scope.rightSelectNgOption = "item as item for item in selectedListItems";
                scope.availableListItems = getUnique(scope.availableListItems);
              }

              function getColor(colorClass, type) {
                var data = {}, color = {};
                switch (colorClass) {
                    case 'pearl':
                        type === 'button' ? (data['btn-default'] = true) : (data['panel-default'] = true);
                        break;
                    case 'blue':
                        type === 'button' ? (data['btn-primary'] = true) : (data['panel-primary'] = true);
                        break;
                    case 'alpha':
                        color = {};
                        color['background-color'] = 'hsl(193, 32%, 49%) !important';color['background-repeat'] = 'repeat-x';color['filter'] = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#b8d3da", endColorstr="#5493a4")';color['background-image'] = '-khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b8d3da), to(#5493a4))';color['background-image'] = '-moz-linear-gradient(top, #b8d3da, #5493a4)';color['background-image'] = '-ms-linear-gradient(top, #b8d3da, #5493a4)';color['background-image'] = '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b8d3da), color-stop(100%, #5493a4))';color['background-image'] = '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b8d3da, #5493a4)';color['background-image'] = '-o-linear-gradient(top, #b8d3da, #5493a4)';color['background-image'] = 'linear-gradient(#b8d3da, #5493a4)';color['border-color'] = '#5493a4 #5493a4 hsl(193, 32%, 41.5%)';color['color'] = '#333 !important';color['text-shadow'] = '0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.49)';color['-webkit-font-smoothing'] = 'antialiased';
                        type === 'button' ? (scope.buttonCssStyle = color) : (scope.panelCssStyle = color);
                        break;
                    case 'sand':
                        color = {};
                        color['background-color'] = 'hsl(33, 32%, 49%) !important';color['background-repeat'] = 'repeat-x';color['filter'] = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#dacbb8", endColorstr="#a48054")';color['background-image'] = '-khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dacbb8), to(#a48054))';color['background-image'] = '-moz-linear-gradient(top, #dacbb8, #a48054)';color['background-image'] = '-ms-linear-gradient(top, #dacbb8, #a48054)';color['background-image'] = '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #dacbb8), color-stop(100%, #a48054))';color['background-image'] = '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dacbb8, #a48054)';color['background-image'] = '-o-linear-gradient(top, #dacbb8, #a48054)';color['background-image'] = 'linear-gradient(#dacbb8, #a48054)';color['border-color'] = '#a48054 #a48054 hsl(33, 32%, 41.5%)';color['color'] = '#333 !important';color['text-shadow'] = '0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.49)';color['-webkit-font-smoothing'] = 'antialiased';
                        type === 'button' ? (scope.buttonCssStyle = color) : (scope.panelCssStyle = color);
                        break;                                    
                    case 'olive':
                        color = {};
                        color['background-color'] = 'hsl(89, 32%, 49%) !important';color['background-repeat'] = 'repeat-x';color['filter'] = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#cadab8", endColorstr="#7ea454")';color['background-image'] = '-khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#cadab8), to(#7ea454))';color['background-image'] = '-moz-linear-gradient(top, #cadab8, #7ea454)';color['background-image'] = '-ms-linear-gradient(top, #cadab8, #7ea454)';color['background-image'] = '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #cadab8), color-stop(100%, #7ea454))';color['background-image'] = '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cadab8, #7ea454)';color['background-image'] = '-o-linear-gradient(top, #cadab8, #7ea454)';color['background-image'] = 'linear-gradient(#cadab8, #7ea454)';color['border-color'] = '#7ea454 #7ea454 hsl(89, 32%, 41.5%)';color['color'] = '#333 !important';color['text-shadow'] = '0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.49)';color['-webkit-font-smoothing'] = 'antialiased';
                        type === 'button' ? (scope.buttonCssStyle = color) : (scope.panelCssStyle = color);
                        break;
                    default:
                        data[colorClass] = true;
                }
                return data;
              }

              function getUnique(array, key) {
                if (array[0] instanceof Object) {
                  var object = {};
                  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                    object[array[i][key]] = array[i];
                  }
                  array = [];
                  for (var objKey in object) {
                    array.push(object[objKey]);
                  }
                  return array;
                } else {
                  return array.sort().filter(function(item, pos, ary) {
                    return !pos || item != ary[pos - 1];
                  });
                }
              }

              function orderSelections() {
                if (scope.selectedListItems[0] instanceof Object) {
                  scope.selectedListItems = $filter('orderBy')(scope.selectedListItems, scope.key);
                } 
                else {
                  scope.selectedListItems = $filter('orderBy')(scope.selectedListItems, 'toString()');
                }
              } 

              scope.setAscendingDescendingOrder = function() {
                if(scope.ascendingOrderFlag) {
                  scope.topLetter = 'Z';
                  scope.bottomLetter = 'A';
                  scope.ascendingOrderFlag = false;
                  if (scope.selectedListItems[0] instanceof Object) {
                    scope.selectedListItems = setOrdering(scope.key, true);
                  }
                  else { 
                    scope.selectedListItems = setOrdering('toString()', true);
                  }
                }
                else { 
                  scope.topLetter = 'A';
                  scope.bottomLetter = 'Z';
                  scope.ascendingOrderFlag = true;
                  if (scope.selectedListItems[0] instanceof Object) {
                    scope.selectedListItems = setOrdering(scope.key, false);
                  }
                  else { 
                    scope.selectedListItems = setOrdering('toString()', false);
                  }
                }
              };

              function setOrdering(orderVariable, reverse) {
                return $filter('orderBy')(scope.selectedListItems, orderVariable, reverse);
              }

              scope.addItemsToRight = function() {
                angular.forEach(scope.leftMouseSelectedItems, function(leftMouseSelectedItem, key) {
                  scope.selectedListItems.push(leftMouseSelectedItem);
                  angular.forEach(scope.availableListItems, function(availableListItem, index) {
                    if (scope.availableListItems[0] instanceof Object) {
                      if (availableListItem[scope.key] === leftMouseSelectedItem[scope.key]) {
                        scope.availableListItems.splice(index, 1);
                      }
                    } else {
                      if (availableListItem === leftMouseSelectedItem) {
                        scope.availableListItems.splice(index, 1);
                      }
                    }
                  });
                });
                scope.leftMouseSelectedItems = [];
                orderSelections();
                setSelectedOptionDisabledEnabled();
              };

              scope.addAllItemsToRight = function() {
                angular.forEach(scope.availableListItems, function(availableListItem, key) {
                  scope.selectedListItems.push(availableListItem);
                });
                scope.availableListItems = [];
                scope.leftMouseSelectedItems = [];
                orderSelections();
                setSelectedOptionDisabledEnabled();
              };

              scope.addItemsToLeft = function() {
                angular.forEach(scope.rightMouseSelectedItems, function(rightMouseSelectedItem, key) {
                  scope.availableListItems.push(rightMouseSelectedItem);
                  angular.forEach(scope.selectedListItems, function(selectedListItem, index) {
                    if (scope.availableListItems[0] instanceof Object) {
                      if (selectedListItem[scope.key] === rightMouseSelectedItem[scope.key]) {
                        scope.selectedListItems.splice(index, 1);
                      }
                    } else {
                      if (selectedListItem === rightMouseSelectedItem) {
                        scope.selectedListItems.splice(index, 1);
                      }
                    }
                  });
                });
                scope.rightMouseSelectedItems = [];
                setSelectedOptionDisabledEnabled();
              };

              scope.addAllItemsToLeft = function() {
                angular.forEach(scope.selectedListItems, function(selectedListItem, key) {
                  scope.availableListItems.push(selectedListItem);
                });
                scope.selectedListItems = [];
                scope.rightMouseSelectedItems = [];
                setSelectedOptionDisabledEnabled();
              };

              function setSelectedOptionDisabledEnabled() {
                scope.isSelectedOptionDisabled = scope.selectedListItems.length<=0;
              }


              scope.addItemsToTop = function() {
                var prevIndex = -1;
                angular.forEach(scope.rightMouseSelectedItems, function(rightMouseSelectedItem, key) {
                  var itemIndex = scope.selectedListItems.indexOf(rightMouseSelectedItem);
                  if (itemIndex - 1 === prevIndex) {
                    prevIndex = itemIndex;
                  } else if (itemIndex > 0) {
                    var itemToMove = scope.selectedListItems.splice(itemIndex, 1);
                    scope.selectedListItems.splice(itemIndex - 1, 0, itemToMove[0]);
                  }
                });
              };

              scope.addItemsToDown = function() {
                var prevIndex = scope.selectedListItems.length;
                angular.forEach(scope.rightMouseSelectedItems.concat().reverse(), function(rightMouseSelectedItem, key) {
                  var itemIndex = scope.selectedListItems.indexOf(rightMouseSelectedItem);
                  if (itemIndex + 1 === prevIndex) {
                    prevIndex = itemIndex;
                  } else if (itemIndex < scope.selectedListItems.length - 1) {
                    var itemToMove = scope.selectedListItems.splice(itemIndex, 1);
                    scope.selectedListItems.splice(itemIndex + 1, 0, itemToMove[0]);
                  }
                });
              };
              setSelectedOptionDisabledEnabled();
            }
          };
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
})(window, window.angular);
```

> ```
>     <div><button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-xs' ng-click='editPermissionFx(selectedList)'><span class='fa
> > fa-check'></span>Save</button>" +
>                        "<button type='button' class='btn btn-link btn-xs' ng-click='editPermissionCancelFx()'>Cancel</button>" +
>                  "</div>"
> ```

as it declared in directive so i am unable to get **editPermissionFx(selectedList)** the selectedList in my controller file.

> And my controller file is:

```
angular.module('mainApp1',['ngListSelect']).controller('myCtrl1',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.editPermission=false;
    $scope.grp=false;
    $scope.showgrp=[];

    $scope.availableList= [
        {name: "John", email: "john@gmail.com"}, 
        {name: "Avinash", email: "avinash@gmail.com"},
        {name:"Priya", email: "priya@gmail.com"}];
    });

    $scope.selectedList = [];
});
```

Comment: 'selectedList` is not declared in your directive. You are binding `selectedListItems` in the directive to `selectedList` in your parent scope. You must add `selectedList` to `$scope` in your controller

Comment: can you please write a code

Comment: Actually i am using ngListSelect dependency http://nidhishkrishnan.github.io/ngListSelect/ and i want to send the selected data through this editPermissionFx(selectedList) but this function is coded in the directive. Therefore i am not getting the value of selectedList in my controller

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a truly *global* variable, the appropriate way to do this is with a service or factory. As a factory:

```
angular.module("MyModule").factory("GlobalSettings", function () {
  return {
    variable1: "value"
  }
});
```

This will give you an inject-able container for the global variable. So you can set this in your directive and read it in your controller. Something like this for the controller:

```
angular.module("MyModule").controller("SomeController", function (GlobalSettings) {
  if (GlobalSettings.variable1 == "somevalue") {
    // Do whatever
  }
});
```

And for the directive

```
angular.module("MyModule").directive("SomeDirective", function (GlobalSettings) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // Whatever
            GlobalSettings.variable1 = "appropriatevalue";
            // Whatever
        }
    }      
});
```

This is the recommended way to share data among controllers and directives.

Comment: how can i use this variable1 in custom directive?

Comment: It works exactly the same, whether you want to inject the factory into a controller or a directive, you just pass it in as a parameter to the function. I'll update the answer to show that as well.

Comment: yes please but if we don't want services or factory to inject so, can't we declare directly in custom directive?? rather than factory or services?

Comment: If this is global data, you should use a factory or service. Or are you referring to an attribute of the directive? Meaning each directive has its own copy?

Comment: yeah i am referring to an attribute of the directive

Comment: Please update the question to say that. From the wording it seemed like you were trying to share global data between the directive and your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedList` is not declared in your directive. You are binding `selectedListItems` in the directive to `selectedList` in your parent scope. You must add `selectedList` to `$scope` in your controller:

```
angular.module("MyModule").controller("SomeController", function ($scope) {
  $scope.selectedList = ["apples", "oranges"];
});
```

Since this controller now places `selectedList` on the `$scope`, you should be able to access it in your markup, exactly the way you showed. Also, if you don't add it to the scope, your directive will have a `$scope.selectedListItems` value of `undefined`.

Comment: But i did that angular.module('mainApp1',['ngListSelect']).controller('myCtrl1',function($scope,$http){
 
 $scope.showgrp=[];

 $scope.availableList = [
  {
   name: "John", email: "john@gmail.com"}
  ];
 $scope.selectedList = [];
});

Comment: Again, why do you only add this as a comment to the answer? Did you not think this was useful to know to someone reading your question? Please add the controller code to the question. And show `editPermissionFx()` while you're at it, along with any JavaScript error messages you find in Chrome Developer Tools. That information should have been on the question you initially asked.